# How to store this password in data base

Tags: php, mysql

```
 <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

include ("connect/connect.php");  

static function generatePassword($length = 8) {
    $chars = "1234567890abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $i = 0;
    $password = "";
    while ($i <= $length) {
        $password .= $chars{mt_rand(0, strlen($chars))};
        $i++;
    }
    return $password;
}

$sql="INSERT INTO `users`(`password`) VALUES ('$password')";

$result=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

i want to store this "$password" in my database. but i can't put this directly to a php file and store it.because i'm getting an error. anyone know how to do this??

Thank you!

Comment: No, we do not know what error message you're getting.

Comment: which error do you get?

Comment: `$password` is never defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the function and store its value inside variable.

```
$pass = generatePassword();
$sql="INSERT INTO `users`(`password`) VALUES ('$pass')";
```

Comment: but after it saved in the database it has only 9 characters..but it should be like this [1911ba1bec6e2301e56c26c16d0d6b76]

Comment: @user2534316 use any hash algorithm to hash it. like sha12($pass).

Comment: how to use md5 to do it?

Comment: @user2534316 Using md5 is really bad idea, but if you want to use it use like `md5($pass)`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use your function.
Try this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `users`(`password`) VALUES ('".generatePassword()."')";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call the function you have defined and store it in the variable `$password`, else no variable $password is defined in your code.

```
$password = generatePassword();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function generatePassword($length = 8) {
    $chars = "1234567890abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $i = 0;
    $password = "";
    while ($i <= $length) {
        $password .= $chars{mt_rand(0, strlen($chars))};
        $i++;
    }
    return $password;
}

$password = generatePassword(8) ;
$sql="INSERT INTO `users`(`password`) VALUES ('{$password}')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have define `generatePassword` function as static function. and You have not defined any class so change function from static function to simple function by removing `static`. and You are usin $password variable but you have not called `generatePassword` function to get value so you need to call function  first. try code given below.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

include ("connect/connect.php");  

function generatePassword($length = 8) {
    $chars = "1234567890abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $i = 0;
    $password = "";
    while ($i <= $length) {
        $password .= $chars{mt_rand(0, strlen($chars))};
        $i++;
    }
    return $password;
}
$password = generatePassword();
$sql="INSERT INTO `users`(`password`) VALUES ('$password')";

$result=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
```